# Spotify Charts API

Tags: python, charts, spotify

Spotify recently made an update to their Spotify Viral Charts, which used to be available [here](http://charts.spotify.com/).

They are now available only via [the web player](https://play.spotify.com/chart/6o9o1UphRtyv10VPuDT80D) itself, and I was wondering if there is a Spotify solution to grab the songs from the Viral charts into Python.

As an example, here is the Global Viral 50 chart I would like to pull data on: `spotify:app:chart:6o9o1UphRtyv10VPuDT80D`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you found info or an announcement suggesting that [charts.spotify.com](http://charts.spotify.com/) is discontinued? According to the discussion on [this Spotify Web API issue](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/23) on Github, the Charts API is not shut down – the data is just not updated at the moment for some reason:

> Without getting into details, I'd just like to add that we can't offer the same level of support of the Charts API as we do for the API presented on Spotify's Developer site. To my knowledge there's no reason as to why the Charts API isn't updated so I'm labeling this as a bug.

I don't think there's another way to (easily) retrieve the viral charts data programmatically.

**UPDATE:** Now there's a notice on [charts.spotify.com](http://charts.spotify.com/) telling that the Charts API is discontinued:

> charts.spotify is deprecated and data will not be refreshed until
>   further notice. Please use the charts located in Spotify Browse for
>   charts-related insights while we work on a more stable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the tracks from a playlist via the web-api

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-playlist/

It shouldn't be much extra work to do it in python, the curl example shows all parameters and headers to send.

Answer (score 0):

There is a page (I believe kept up by a third-party archivist) called spotifycharts.com that I think has everything you want. I haven't tried scraping it programmatically, but it shouldn't be too hard.